# std::stringstream "str" returning nothing?

Tags: c++, string, templates

I'm having trouble with `std::stringstream`. My function as seen below returns absolutely nothing. Even when trying a stringstream outside of the template function it still returns nothing when .str() is called.

```
template < class T > std::string toString( const T &t )
{
    std::stringstream temp;
    temp << t;
    std::cout << temp.str() << std::endl;
    return temp.str();
}

std::string test = "test" + toString( 1 );
std::cout << test << std::endl;
std::stringstream stream;
stream << "test" << 1;
std::cout << stream.str() << std::endl;
```

Both of these output only "test"

**Fixed**

Had to remove `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` and `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG_PEDANTIC` from my preprocessor macros.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error.  Please show a full code sample that demonstrates it.

Comment: Works here: http://ideone.com/2Tzbb. The problem must be somewhere else... what's your toolchain?

Comment: Do you have an std::string toString(int t) somewhere?

Comment: @Industrial's suggestion sounds realistic.

Comment: Ok, I seemed to have fixed the problem now by removing `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG_PEDANTIC` from my Preprocessor Macros.

Comment: And how do you think the removal of these explain the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try `ostringstream` instead of `stringstream`.

**== UPDATE ==**

I compiled your code with GCC 4.6.1, and it works as-is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

template < class T > std::string toString( const T &t )
{
    std::stringstream temp;
    temp << t;
    std::cout << temp.str() << std::endl;
    return temp.str();
}

int main()
{
  std::string test = "test" + toString( 1 );
  std::cout << test << std::endl;
  std::stringstream stream;
  stream << "test" << 1;
  std::cout << stream.str() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
test1
test1
```

Comment: That is not the reason, `stringstream` is like a combination of `ostringstream` and `istringstream`.

Comment: @Xeo Oops, you are right. I tried to compile the code with `stringstream` and it works (see above). It would be of help to know the type of the compiler and the compile options to OP uses.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

template < class T > std::string toString( const T &t )
{
    std::stringstream temp;
    temp << t;
    std::cout << temp.str() << std::endl;
    return temp.str();
}

int main(){
    std::string test = "test" + toString( 1 );
    std::cout << test << std::endl;
    std::stringstream stream;
    stream << "test" << 1;
    std::cout << stream.str() << std::endl;
}
```

Outputs

```
1
test1
test1
```

For me with Clang 3.1, GCC 4.4.5 and MSVC 10, so your problem lies elsewhere. Please try just the code above in a new project and see if the problem persists. If not, the suggestions by @Industrial-antidepressant sounds quite realistic, i.e. that you have a better matching overload lying around somewhere.

Comment: I guess I was somewhat vague, I know the code works. It worked when I first started the project, but now I've come back to it after some time and it has stopped working which is quite strange.

Comment: @jackyyll: Please do as my answers says at the bottom and report back.